# Camera Zoom Issue Windows 8

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

i am trying to provide the Zooming functionality in camera app, for this purpose I am using MediaCapture class, all the other capabilities of MediaCapture are working properly except of Zoom, I am using the following code to achieve the zoom:

```
private void zoomSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    m_mediaCaptureMgr.VideoDeviceController.Zoom.TrySetValue(zoomSlider.Value);
}
```

But its not working
plz tell me how to do it??

**EDIT: Code formatting correction**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can also Zoom camera view with like this in XAML

```
<CaptureElement x:Name="previewElement1" Width="1366" Height="672">
                <CaptureElement.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform  x:Name="zoom"/>
                </CaptureElement.RenderTransform>
                </CaptureElement>

<Slider  Width="30" Height="300" Name="zoomSlider" ValueChanged="zoomSlider_ValueChanged_1" />
```

and in C#

```
private void zoomSlider_ValueChanged_1(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        zoom.ScaleX = zoomSlider.Value;
        zoom.ScaleY = zoomSlider.Value;
        zoom.CenterX = 683;
        zoom.CenterY = 384;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`<ScaleTransform>` does not modify the zoom of the camera. It just enlarges the image, so you will see the same image more pixelated.

The zoom of the camera is controlled by `ZoomControl` class. It is located inside `MediaCapture` class.

Example: `Slider` element changes the zoom of the camera.

```xml
<CaptureElement x:Name="captureElement"
                Stretch="UniformToFill" />

<Slider x:Name="sliderZoom"
        Width="250"
        ValueChanged="sliderZoom_ValueChanged"/>
```

Configuration of the `Slider`:

```cs
MediaCapture _mediaCapture;

// Initialization of the MediaCapture ...

if(this._mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.ZoomControl.Supported)
{
    sliderZoom.Minimum = this._mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.ZoomControl.Min;
    sliderZoom.Maximum = this._mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.ZoomControl.Max;
    sliderZoom.StepFrequency = this._mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.ZoomControl.Step;
}
```

Modify the zoom of the camera when the `Slider` changes its value:

```cs
private void sliderZoom_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(this._mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.ZoomControl.Supported)
    {
        this._mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.ZoomControl.Value = (float)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

If `StepFrequency` is not equal to `ZoomControl.Step` this error will be shown when trying to modify the zoom:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in ....exe but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: Zoom factor
Additional information: The parameter is incorrect.
```